# Need any design ideas for filtering properties of an object

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, reflection, attributes

Assume there is a class called HouseHoldItems. It may have a number of varied items like

```
Class HouseHoldItems
{ 
  TV,
  Fridge,
  Hammer,
  Chair,
  Watch,
  Shoes,  
}
```

I want a way to come up with a pattern where I can designate few of the items as say 'Electronic', 'ClothBased', 'Iron','Electric'. Then I would like to be able to get the list of electronic items and so forth.

We have our business entities on top of which we designate items are filterable, searchable, user can see or not and other similar behaviours. In the UI, we have screens that display each of these list accordingly.

I would like to come up with a generic design and a way through which I can apply such characteritics to properties of my objects. For now, I can think of 'Attributes' and Reflection in my mind to achieve this but want to know if there is any known pattern that is already existing that may help to achieve this in a more nicer way.

Thanks
Mani

Comment: that looks more like an Enum than a Class

Comment: I'm doing this in database with CategoryType and Category, that is referencing CategoryType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern may be [Query pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html). Say you have Select() method with a criteria argument as "Electronic" which returns the list of requested items.

```
Item[] HouseHoldItems.Select(string criteria);
```

Of cause you need to implement this method.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going in the right direction:

```
public enum Category { Electronic, ClothBased, // etc. }

abstract class HouseholdItem { 
    private readonly Category category;
    public Category Category { get; }
    public HouseholdItem(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}

class Television : HouseholdItem {
    public Television() : base(Category.Electronic) { }
}
```

You can even make `Category` into a `class` if you need.

Comment: All enum guidelines tell us not to use enums if the set of values is likely to change. I would assume that's the case here

Comment: @Dyppl: "You can even make `Category` into a `class` if you need."

Answer (score 0):

Don't use attributes for this. Attributes shouldn't be used for some business logic, it's part of a mechanism.

If I understand correctly, what you have here is classic [many-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationship between items and "categories". There are many ways to represent such relationship.

If you are going to store data in relational database then the most natural way is to introduce an object that links one item together with one category. Few such objects may exist for each item. That's the way Many-To-Many relationship are presented in relational databases.

If you only need to store this relationship at runtime, you can just add a list of categories as a field of Item class and a list of items in category as a field of category class. Make sure that they are synchronized at any moment and it should suffice. It'll be easy to get the information you need.

So, the key point is to create a class `Category` or `Tag` and to make an instance of it for each category like "electric" and "clothbased", then it's the matter of linking two together - either through direct linking from both sides or through a "relationship" object.